# Switching between git branches in Eclipse

Tags: git

I have cloned two branches inside same eclipse workspace. Hence it has 2 cloned repositories. Whenever I launch eclipse it opens one of the repositories. How to switch eclipse to point to the other repository?

Comment: Are you trying to switch to another branch or to another repository?

Comment: When you clone 2 branches, you will have 2 branches locally but one repository.So if you want eclipse to point to other branch just use `git checkout branchName` in your console.

Answer (score 2):

To switch branches from within Eclipse

1. Right click project in the explorer window (by default it's on the
   left side)
2. Go to Team
3. Go to Switch To
4. Select a branch to switch to

Eclipse will now update the project and files to match the branch

Comment: Explorer of  eclipse kepler don't ve 'Team' option on its right click. As well wanna mention under Git Repositories, there are two cloned local repository pointing to diff branches.

Comment: Right click your project name

Comment: You cloned two repositories or two branches from a repository?

Comment: @Theepag you replied to a 7 year old comment, I doubt he remembers

Comment: @Tim haha let's hope

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 repositories (one branch in each repository), this means that you unnecessary created them. You can have both branches in only one repository.

In Git Repositories tab, after clone a repository, you should click it with right button -> "Fetch from origin" -> Configure -> Add -> type wanted branch -> Save and Fetch.

If you'd like use one branch per repository, so to show others repositories, in Git Repositories tab you should click "Add an existing local Git Repository to this view" icon and select the wanted repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the terminal

```
Git checkout banchName
```

And if you clone 2 branches you will have one repository with 2 branches.